# reverse the string,but it crashed

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse_string(char *string){
char *p = string;
while(*p !='\0'){
    p++;
}
p--;

while( string < p ){
    char temp;
    temp = *string;
    *string = *p;
    *p = temp;
    }
}
int main(){
    char *string = "abcdefg";
    reverse_string(string);
    printf("%s\n",*string);
}
```

I want to reverse the string.But it doesn't work and the code crashes.
*string can't be changed？or what's wrong?

Comment: `*string` can't be changed. and Logic bad.

Comment: You also forgot to update your pointers in your while loop, it’ll never stop looping.

Comment: Does anyone mind explaining why this particular question is so bad? Sure, it could be formulated a bit better, but it seems a legit programming question to me? EDIT: No longer needed, it's apparently duplicate.

Comment: note : `p--;` is likely to be in UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
char *string = "abcdefg";
```

to

```
char string[] = "abcdefg";
```

And take a look to [Question 1.3 2 of C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html)

---

`"%s"` format is for strings, but here:

```
printf("%s\n",*string);
```

you are passing an `int`, change to:

```
printf("%s\n", string);
```

---

This is an infinite loop:

```
while( string < p ){
    char temp;
    temp = *string;
    *string = *p;
    *p = temp;
}
```

You need to decrement `p` somewhere.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on why that would work? The OP's code crashes because he is attempting to fiddle with memory of a `const` object ("abcdefg" is of type `const char *`) which points into `.text` sections of the binary and therefore would be loaded by the OS/loader as write protected.

Comment: @user268396, sure, I was editing :P